# DHCP does not work with ethernet-connected devices, but works with wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, dhcp, switch

I am having a weird issue starting today. I have a fiber internet connection with an ONT. The ONT just has one ethernet port which leads into a cheap 4-port switch (not a router). From the switch, one ethernet cable goes into a wireless Amplifi mesh router, and another ethernet cable goes into my son's PC (which does not have a wifi card).

Now, up until today, this has worked perfectly. The wifi router has its own DHCP which hands out LAN IP addresses to all the wireless devices here. The WAN address of the wifi router is thus the same as my public IP.

First: When I start to think about it, I do not exactly understand *why* this has worked, since the absence of a router should mean that my son's PC gets the same WAN IP address as the wifi router, right? Yet it has worked without issues for a year.

Now, starting today, only wifi works. The wifi router still gets the WAN IP address. But it seems like my ISP's DHCP server is no longer handing out an IP address to any ethernet-connected device, no matter if I plug the ethernet cable directly into the ONT or into a port in the switch. The mysterious part (at least to me) is that the wifi router is also a cabled device - it goes into the switch, but it *still* gets a fine WAN IP address. Any other cabled device that I connect to the switch/ONT only gets a 169.x.x.x address.

An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I should add that I have tested with two other laptops plugged into the switch with an ethernet cable, with the same result, so this is not an issue with my son's PC.

Comment: In most scenarios, the ONT is typically a bridge and it just passes thru the public IP. It is not a router. In other cases it is a router also. And sometimes there is this weird mix of the two. In any case, if the expected configuration is that the public IP address is “passed thru” to the connected device then of course only one device can have that address at any one time. So what happens is it will only respond one time to a DHCP request. Once the IP is assigned to a device it won’t provide an IP to any other device. You may have to power cycle the ONT to connect a new device.

Comment: Why it ever worked? It could be one of those “weird” kind of devices. Or maybe you had more than 1 public IP purchased? Maybe the PC was actually connected to wireless the whole time? Hard to know now, after the fact.

Comment: @Appleoddity Thank you. I have power cycled the ONT 2-3 times, no luck. The PC (my son's) has no wifi card, so it has most definitely been on cabled (ethernet) connection. You are correct that one explanation could be that we are allowed multiple public IPs, I will check that.

Comment: Did your son's PC ever need to talk to something on your home's Wi-Fi, like printing to a Wi-Fi-attached printer, or backing up to a Wi-Fi-attached network drive (NAS) or shared folder on another PC? If so, did it work? If it did, your Amplifi was probably (accidentally) in "NAT on a stick" a.k.a one-armed NAT mode, where it bridged its WAN and LAN ports.

Comment: @Spiff No, that has not been the case. But the PC went online again by itself after some hours, getting a different WAN IP than the Amplifi router, so apparently we are eligible for at least two public IPs here. However, it then jumped off again the next day for a few hours, and then back on. Not sure what's going on. I know our ISP has been making some changes this week due to being merged with another fiber company.